# Why is this a linear matrix inequality in $x,t$?

Tags: analysis, optimization

I'm given the following inequality

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 t & (Ax+ b)^T \\
 (Ax+b) & P_0+x_1P_1+\dots+x_nP_n
\end{bmatrix}\succcurlyeq  0$$

is said to be a linear matrix inequality in variables $x,t$. The general for of a LMI I knwo is the form $x_1A_1+\dots+x_nA_n\succcurlyeq  0$ how can the above be seen of this type in $x, t$?

Comment: You forgot the $A_0$ term: that should be $A_0 + x_1 A_1 + \cdots + x_n A_n \succeq 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the matrix $A$ has size $m \times n$. Let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ denote the columns of $A$. Define
$$
M_0 = \pmatrix{0 & b^T\\b & P_0}, \quad 
M_k = \pmatrix{0 & a_k^T\\ a_k & P_k} \text{ for } k = 1,\dots,n, 
\\M_{n+1} = \pmatrix{1 & 0_{1 \times m}\\0_{m \times 1} & 0_{m \times m}}.
$$
We can write the inequality presented in the form
$$
M_0 + x_1 M_1 + \cdots + x_n M_n + t M_{n+1} \succeq 0.
$$